# What is an "Accuser"?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

The new *Guardians of the Galaxy* movie features *Ronan The Accuser*.  I've read a few of the comics, including one issue where Gamora is confronted by an Accuser.

The Accuser in the comics seems to be acting in a bounty hunter capacity, but Ronan does not seem to be doing anything similar.

**Who, or what are the Accusers?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**A branch of Kree law enforcement/military.**

I don’t know if the Marvel Wiki is considered accurate, but it has an article about the [Accuser Corps](http://marvel.wikia.com/Accuser_Corps_(Earth-616)) that sounds plausible:

> The Accuser Corps are the Kree Empire’s fist of judgement who brings judgement to those who are accused of their crimes against the empire.

We know that Ronan was a Kree, and [apparently enrolled in the Accuser Corps](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ronan_the_Accuser):

> Upon the completion of his formal education, Ronan was enrolled in the Kree Public Accuser Corps.

I can’t be sure, but I think that’s probably how the term “Accuser” is used.

Comment: You are correct in your use. Accusers were not bounty-hunters, per se, but may employ them to find Kree citizens who were accused of crimes against the Kree empire. However, having an Accuser after you was a sign of great affront to the Empire. Normally, they would send a Sentry to deal with you and call it a day, two if you were particularly bad-ass. If you were more than a Sentry could handle, an Accuser was dispatched. Rarely was anything else needed after that...

Comment: They're actually very similar to Judges in nature. They hunt down criminals, judge them, and (if warranted) execute them on the spot. The whole process is called "accusing", just like Judge Dredd would "judge" someone.

Comment: Also ties in well with his obsession with bringing justice to the Xandar for his "father, and his father...".